# backbone handling rails virtual field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I added a method in my model that calculates the current progress.
I also overrode the as_json method to include the virtual field in my response.

```
def progress
   //code to get progress
end


def as_json(options = { })
  super((options || { }).merge({
    :methods => [:progress]
  }))
end
```

The problem I have now is that I get an UnknownAttributeError because backbone is trying to submit the field "progress".

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: progress):
```

I tried adding this to the first line of the update method in the controller

```
params.delete('progress')
```

Comment: it was nested so i had to do this...
params[:assignment].delete('progress')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was nested so I had to do this

```
params[:assignment].delete('progress')
```

I also added this to the model

```
attr_reader :progress
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your progress method out of your `attr_accessible` line and that should clear things up.

I had the same problem, and the folks at ThoughBot support ([Backbone.js on Rails](https://learn.thoughtbot.com/products/1-backbone-js-on-rails)) helped me out (highly recommend that book, comes with support for your app).